# C# ThreadStaticAttribute marked fields are automatically released when thread dies?

Tags: c#, multithreading, static

I discovered `ThreadStaticAttribute`, and I have a lot of questions about it:
all my previous thread-dependent static information was implemented as a static dictionary in which TKey is Thread, and when I wanted to access it, I used Thread.CurrentThread and that works. But this requires maintenance because if a thread dies, I have to delete the corresponding entry from the dictionary. And I also need to consider thread safety and a lot of other matters.

By using `ThreadStaticAttribute`, all these matters seem to be solved, but I need to be sure of it. My questions are: do I need to delete the instance held by `ThreadStaticAttribute` marked fields, somehow, before the thread dies?? Where is the information on that field held?? It is in the instance of a `Thread` object, or something like that, so that when it is not used anymore, the garbage collector automatically discards it? Are there performance penalties? What ones? Is it faster than using a Keyed collection like I was doing?

I need clarification on how `ThreadStaticAttribute` works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No you do not need to delete instances of values help in a field which is tagged with `ThreadStatic`.  The garbage collector will automatically pick them up when both the thread and the object are no longer reachable by rooted objects.

The only exception here is if the value implements `IDisposable` and you want to actively dispose of it.  In general this is a hard problem to solve for a number of reasons.  It's much simpler to not have values which implement `IDisposable` and are in a `ThreadStatic` field.

As to where this field is actually stored, it's somewhat irrelevant.  All you need to be concerned about is that it will behave like any other object in .Net.  The only two behavior differences are

1. The field will reference a different value per accessing thread.
2. The initializer for the field will only be run once (in practice, it's a bad idea to have any).

Answer (score 6):

Marking a static member variable as [ThreadStatic] tells the compiler to allocate it in the thread's memory area (eg. where the thread's stack is allocated) rather than in the global memory area.  Thus, each thread will have its own copy (which are guaranteed to be initialized to the default value for that type, eg. null, 0, false, etc; do not use in-line initializers as they will only initialize it for one thread).

So, when the thread goes away, so does its memory area, releasing the reference.  Of course if it's something that needs more immediate disposal (open file streams, etc) instead of waiting for background garbage collection, you might want to make sure you do that before the thread exits.

There could be a limit to the amount of [ThreadStatic] space available, but it should be sufficient for sane uses.  It should be somewhat faster than accessing a keyed collection (and more easily thread-safe), and I think it's comparable to accessing a normal static variable.

**Correction:** I have since heard that accessing ThreadStatic variables is somewhat slower than accessing normal static variables.  I'm not sure if it is even actually faster than accessing a keyed collection, but it does avoid issues of orphans (which was your question) and needing locking for threadsafety which would complicate a keyed-collection approach.

Comment: The compiler quite literally does nothing for the `ThreadStatic` attribute.  It is entirely handled by the CLR

Comment: Okay, but taking "compiler" in a metaphorical sense rather than strictly literal sense, you get the idea as far as how to use the attribute.